# Campos hidden aparecerem/se modificarem com um select multiple

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte select:

```
<select name="hierarquia[]" multiple>
    <option value="Usuário" selected> Usuário</option>
    <option value="Moderador" selected> Moderador</option>
    <option value="Administrador"> Administrador</option>
</select>
```

E também tenho seguintes campos (exemplos):

```
<input type="hidden" id="campo-1" name ="campo-1" value="0000">
<input type="hidden" id="campo-2" name ="campo-2" value="0000">
```

Estou montando um painel administrativo, onde a configuração dos formulários vem automaticamente. Eu seto os dados da tabela do SQL em uma variável, chamo uma função que puxa um array com os campos e os tipos deles (vou voltar nisso depois) e a partir de uma estrutura de repetição, o software cria todos os inputs, selects, radios, etc.

O fato, é que existem alguns campos que são especiais, só aparecem quando você adiciona um tipo de usuário específico, evidenciado por `$_GET['mode']`, ou seja, se esse `$_GET['mode'] = 'moderador'`, ele exibe os campos ocultos cabíveis ao registro ao moderador de forma correta, caso `$_GET['mode'] = 'admin'`, ele exibe os do administradores, mas não os do moderador, e assim por diante.

Esses campos são hidden por um único motivo: eu valido todas as entradas que chegam. Se a função que valida não encontra o `$_GET`, a única resposta que ele encontrará como válida será o 0000.

A questão, é que o campo-1 ou o campo-2 não são necessariamente texts, mas podem ser select com opções variadas, carregadas a partir do banco, radios, até files, ou outras diversas coisas.

Enquanto escrevia isso, me vieram duas ideias na cabeça: ao trocar o select, verificava qual(is) estavam selecionados  e dependendo do caso, carregando novos campos via ajax (?). Aí que pegaria, já que não poderiam ter campos que fossem carregados duas vezes e que esses campos carregados substituam os hiddens. Isso também pediria uma modificação na validação, mas providenciável.

A outra ideia seria um pouco menos evasiva, menos radical e preferível. Ao mudar o campo do select, recarregaria a página com o `$_GET['mode']` correspondente ao que foi selecionado. O grande problema é que eu não poderia perder os dados que já foram preenchidos.

Deixo essa com vocês, preciso alterar entre diversos campos quando opções diferentes forem selecionadas, inclusive podendo mais de uma opção ser selecionada. Se possível lancem ideias novas ou funções para utilizar.

**Detalhe adicional:** os `$_GET['mode']` podem estar no formato: `$_GET['mode'] = 'admin,moderador'`

Comment: como você está montando a página? Pode postar o código?

Comment: Estou longe do meu código fonte, quando pegar meu note edito aqui!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E se você usasse o `jQuery` para verificar os modos selecionados/deselecionados e exibir/ocultar os campos no evento `change` do select?

Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$(document).on('change', '#multiple' function(){
    $('#multiple option').each(function(i, e){ 
      var mode = $(e).data("mode");
      var type = $(e).data("type");

      $('[data-mode=' + mode + ']').show();

      if (type != undefined || type != ''){
          $('[data-mode=' + mode + ']').attr('type', type);
      }
    });
});
```

mas para este exemplo funcionar você deverá adicionar nos seus inputs dois atributos `data-`. o `data-mode` e o `data-type`.

- `data-mode` => o modo que o input deve ser ativado;
- `data-type` => o tipo do input quando ele for ativado;

Então, segundo o exemplo que você deu, os inputs ficariam assim:

```
<input type="hidden" data-mode="moderador" data-type="date" id="campo-1" name ="campo-1" value="0000">
<input type="hidden" data-mode="administrador" data-type="file" id="campo-2" name ="campo-2" value="0000">
```

Neste caso, o primero input será ativado para o modo `moderador` e será do tipo `date`, enquanto o segundo será ativado para o modo `administrador` e será do tipo `file`.

Este exemplo é válido também para qualquer tipo de input, select, textarea, etc..., basta ter o atributo `data-mode`. Mas para elementos que não forem inputs, como selects por exemplo, deve verificar se existe o atributo `data-type` e caso não exista simplesmente exibir o controle.

**Edição:**

Caso você necessite carregar dados para preencher um select ao exibi-lo, você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<select name="nome" data-ajax-load="true" data-url="/dados.php"></select>
```

E alterar o evento `change` para compreender estes dois novos atributos, ficando assim:

```
$(document).on('change', '#multiple' function(){
    $('#multiple option').each(function(i, e){ 
      var mode = $(e).data("mode");
      var type = $(e).data("type");
      var ajax = $(e).data("ajax-load");

      if (ajax)
      {
          var url = $(e).data("url");

          $.ajax({
             cache: false,
             type:  tipo,
             data:  data,
             url: location.origin + "/" + url,
             success: function (response) {
                $(e).html(response);
             }
          });
      }

      $('[data-mode=' + mode + ']').show();

      if (type != undefined || type != ''){
          $('[data-mode=' + mode + ']').attr('type', type);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: É uma solução interessante, mas e se fosse um select com determinados dados da DB?

Comment: Caso esses dados sejam dinâmicos, devem ser carregados somente ao serem exibidos você poderia usar ajax. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Resposta resolveu totalmente o problema que eu tive, infelizmente tive que modificar o projeto e me pediram pra alterar para tabelas individuais para cada um na hierarquia. Futuramente seu código vai ser aproveitado. :)

Answer (score 2):

Podes recorrer a um simples JavaScript para fazeres o que queres.

Para fazeres isso podes ir fazendo o ***submit*** do formulário, para a própria página, sempre que alteras o teu `select` da seguinte forma:

```
<form id='formId' action=''>
<!-- ... -->
<select id="hierarquia" name="hierarquia[]" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
```

No caso de precisar de gravar o formulário em outra página tens de ter em atenção que tens de retirar a `action` no `onchange`:

```
<form id='formId' action='gravar.php'>
<!-- ... -->
<select id="hierarquia" name="hierarquia[]"
   onchange="document.getElementById('formId').action='';this.form.submit();" >
```

Depois é só apanhares todos os campos com o `POST` e colocares os valores apanhados nos teus campos:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $value_campo1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'campo-1');
    $hierarquia   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hierarquia');
    //outros valores que precises apanhar
}
```

Exemplo de um `input`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="campo-1" name ="campo-1" 
   value="<?php ($value_campo1 != NULL) ? echo $value_campo1 : echo "0000"?>">
```

Exemplo de um `select` vindo da BD:

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query( $connection , $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $selected = "";
    // verifica a seleção que já foi feita depois do submit
    if($row['hierarquia']==$hierarquia)   
        $selected = "  selected=\"selected\"";

    echo "<option $selected value='{$row['hierarquia']}'> {$row['hierarquia']} </option>";
}
```

Quanto ao aparecer os campos que queres consoante o `mode` basta fazer a verificação antes de mostrar o campo;

```
if($_GET['mode']=='admin')
{
?>
     <!-- campo(s) de admin -->
<?php
}
else if($_GET['mode']=='moderador')
{
?>
    <!-- campo(s) de moderador -->
<?php
}
```

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, mas não existe esse arquivo 'gravar.php' e sequer é possível adicionar-lo.

Comment: Isso é indiferente, é só não colocares o gravar.php.

Comment: Vê a minha edição @GabrielTadraMainginski

Comment: Ah fiz propositadamente com `if` + `echo` e com condição ternária + HTML de propósito para veres as duas formas.